# Use singular for tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

The first tags use pluar form like `hidden-services`. I propose to use singular form like `hidden-service` for all tags.

Comment: Most sites use the singular in tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I disagree, I think all tags should be plural (eg. [hidden-services](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hidden-services)). This is pretty standard.

For example, look at the [about](https://tor.stackexchange.com/about) page; the tag examples are plural there. Or look at the tags on other popular sites (eg. [TeX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags))... they're mostly plural.

Also, it just makes sense. A tag (probably) contains multiple questions; not a single one. A tag should read like: "questions about [hidden-services](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hidden-services)" not "a question about a [hidden-service](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hidden-service)".

As Hiroto pointed out, they should be singular when they're about a specific thing (not a collection) that doesn't really have plurality, eg. [tor](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tor) (that tag is obviously not a good idea for other reasons... it's kind of a given).

Comment: Plural for collections of things. The only time they're singular is when they are about a specific object (e.g. [tag:tor] or [tag:google-chrome])

Comment: @Hiroto Good point; updated the answer.

Comment: Oops, I accidentally created the "bridge" tag singular. How can I fix this?