# Tag renaming: guard -> guard-relays

Tags: discussion, tags

We have three relay categories:  [relays](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/relays), [exit-relays](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exit-relays), and [guard](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guard).

The first is for general relay related questions, whereas the latter two are for specific exit and guard related things.

I propose we rename [guard](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guard) to [guard-relays](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guard-relays).

First of all, this would make the tag a [plural](https://tor.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14/use-singular-for-tags).  Secondly, this would match the [exit-relays](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exit-relays) name.

Answer (score 1):

From my perspective the tag [guard-nodes](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guard-nodes) or [entry-guards](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/entry-guards) sound more familiar. As far as I see those are more used inside the 'Tor universe'.

I totally agree to use the plural form.

Comment: -nodes sounds fine.  But we should probably also call them exit-nodes then, shouldn't we?

Comment: We can make both and i.e use [tag:exit-nodes] as default and [tag:exit-relays] as alias which points to -nodes.